# Numbers 19 Why is the heifer sacrificed outside the camp?

Tags: numbers

Numbers 19:1
The Lord said to Moses and Aaron: 2“This is a requirement of the law that the Lord has commanded: Tell the Israelites to bring you a red heifer without defect or blemish and that has never been under a yoke. 3Give it to Eleazar the priest; it is to be taken outside the camp and slaughtered in his presence. 4Then Eleazar the priest is to take some of its blood on his finger and sprinkle it seven times toward the front of the tent of meeting.

Comment: Additional research : https://hoshanarabbah.org/blog/2013/06/10/red-heifer-explained/

Comment: Related verses: Hebrews 13:12-13

Answer (score 1):

Could it be as simple as being a specific example of the practice of slaughtering *all* animals outside of the camp?

Even today, when one is camping, one doesn't clean fish or meat anywhere near the camp.  Otherwise the fresh blood etc. would attract animals at night.

Answer (score 0):

Pulpit Commentary

> Verse 3. Without the camp. The bodies of those animals which were offered for **the sin of the congregation were always burnt outside the camp**, the law thus testifying that sin and death had no proper place within the city of God. In this case, however, the whole sacrifice was performed outside the camp, and was only brought into relation with the national sanctuary by the sprinkling of the blood in that direction. Various symbolic reasons have been assigned to this fact, but none are satisfactory except the following: -
>
> 1. It served to intensify the conviction, which the whole of this ordinance was intended to bring home to the minds of men, that death was an awful thing, and that everything connected with it was wholly foreign to the presence and habitation of the living God.
> 2. It served to mark with more emphasis the **contrast** between this one offering, which was perhaps almost the only one they had in the wilderness, and those which ought to have been offered continually according to the Levitical ordinances. The red heifer stood quite outside the number of ordinary victims as demanded by the law, and therefore **it was not slain at any hallowed altar, nor, necessarily, by any hallowed hand.**
> 3. It served to **prefigure** in a wonderful and indeed startling way **the sacrifice of Christ outside the gate**.

Hebrews 13:11

> Although the high priest brings the blood of animals into the Holy Place as a sacrifice for sin, the bodies are burned outside the camp.